# bash shell save command output to a file and run in background, but it still prints on screen

Tags: bash

CentOS bash shell, I want command write output to a file, and run in the background, I use `cmd > myfile &`  but sometimes, it still writes to screen.
for example, the following `siege` command writes request/response to screen, but at last the command prints an overall information on screen.
I don't understand why with `> file` and `&` it still outputs something on screen. The overall infromation is not error.

```
siege -H "Content-Type:application/json" -c 10 -r 1000 'http://h1:9091/identity/co POST < identity_image.json' > pressure_image.log
```

```
Transactions:                  99995 hits
Availability:                 100.00 %
Elapsed time:                9970.79 secs
Data transferred:              28.51 MB
Response time:                  0.99 secs
Transaction rate:              10.03 trans/sec
Throughput:                     0.00 MB/sec
Concurrency:                    9.94
Successful transactions:       99995
Failed transactions:               5
Longest transaction:           16.27
Shortest transaction:           0.14
```

Comment: Maybe `siege` is sending output to the standard error stream? Try `2> /dev/null`. Or if you want to capture that stuff add `2>&1`.

Comment: _outputs something_ : You forgot to redirect stderr, i.e. `2>errlog`. Aside from this, it **could** be that siege also outputs something directly to the console. I don't know siege and can't say for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`siege` is writing those messages to stderr, not stdout.

See: https://github.com/JoeDog/siege/blob/3836e878b827faaa46c79c4c3eab70e5763da472/src/main.c#L529

From that, it is apparent that you can either

- also redirect stderr: `siege [...] >logfile 2>&1 &`
- or supply the "[quiet](https://github.com/JoeDog/siege/blob/master/doc/siege.pod)" flag: `siege -q [...] >logfile &`

Comment: that `siege` outputs result information in `stderr`. Thanks